# How to make OpenCV works with 3D markless object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, augmented-reality, opencv

**spec I use:**
Windows 10,
python 3.7,
opencv-contrib-python==4.5.3.56

I am trying to project a 3D object on a markless card, but the 3D object is flying everywhere when the camera opens(main.py runs) as below:

[image]

As we can see the fox is flying everywhere within the footage, that is the fox.obj should be projected while showing the card.

**Here we have 4 files place in the same folder (main.py, objloader_simple.py, fox.obj, model.jpg)**

**main.py** (click to run)

```
import argparse
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math
import os
from objloader_simple import *

MIN_MATCHES = 10
DEFAULT_COLOR = (0, 0, 0)


def main():
    homography = None 
    camera_parameters = np.array([[800, 0, 320], [0, 800, 240], [0, 0, 1]])
    orb = cv2.ORB_create()
    bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)
    dir_name = os.getcwd()
    model = cv2.imread(os.path.join(dir_name, 'model.jpg'), 0)
    kp_model, des_model = orb.detectAndCompute(model, None)
    obj = OBJ(os.path.join(dir_name, 'fox.obj'), swapyz=True)  
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            print("Unable to capture video")
            return 
        kp_frame, des_frame = orb.detectAndCompute(frame, None)
        matches = bf.match(des_model, des_frame)
        matches = sorted(matches, key=lambda x: x.distance)

        if len(matches) > MIN_MATCHES:
            src_pts = np.float32([kp_model[m.queryIdx].pt for m in matches]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
            dst_pts = np.float32([kp_frame[m.trainIdx].pt for m in matches]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
            homography, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC, 5.0)
            if args.rectangle:
                h, w = model.shape
                pts = np.float32([[0, 0], [0, h - 1], [w - 1, h - 1], [w - 1, 0]]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
                dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts, homography)
                frame = cv2.polylines(frame, [np.int32(dst)], True, 255, 3, cv2.LINE_AA)  
            if homography is not None:
                try:
                    projection = projection_matrix(camera_parameters, homography)
                    frame = render(frame, obj, projection, model, False)
                except:
                    pass
            if args.matches:
                frame = cv2.drawMatches(model, kp_model, frame, kp_frame, matches[:10], 0, flags=2)
            cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

        else:
            print("Not enough matches found - %d/%d" % (len(matches), MIN_MATCHES))

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    return 0

def render(img, obj, projection, model, color=False):
    vertices = obj.vertices
    scale_matrix = np.eye(3) * 3
    h, w = model.shape

    for face in obj.faces:
        face_vertices = face[0]
        points = np.array([vertices[vertex - 1] for vertex in face_vertices])
        points = np.dot(points, scale_matrix)
        points = np.array([[p[0] + w / 2, p[1] + h / 2, p[2]] for p in points])
        dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(points.reshape(-1, 1, 3), projection)
        imgpts = np.int32(dst)
        if color is False:
            cv2.fillConvexPoly(img, imgpts, DEFAULT_COLOR)
        else:
            color = hex_to_rgb(face[-1])
            color = color[::-1]  # reverse
            cv2.fillConvexPoly(img, imgpts, color)

    return img

def projection_matrix(camera_parameters, homography):
    homography = homography * (-1)
    rot_and_transl = np.dot(np.linalg.inv(camera_parameters), homography)
    col_1 = rot_and_transl[:, 0]
    col_2 = rot_and_transl[:, 1]
    col_3 = rot_and_transl[:, 2]
    l = math.sqrt(np.linalg.norm(col_1, 2) * np.linalg.norm(col_2, 2))
    rot_1 = col_1 / l
    rot_2 = col_2 / l
    translation = col_3 / l
    c = rot_1 + rot_2
    p = np.cross(rot_1, rot_2)
    d = np.cross(c, p)
    rot_1 = np.dot(c / np.linalg.norm(c, 2) + d / np.linalg.norm(d, 2), 1 / math.sqrt(2))
    rot_2 = np.dot(c / np.linalg.norm(c, 2) - d / np.linalg.norm(d, 2), 1 / math.sqrt(2))
    rot_3 = np.cross(rot_1, rot_2)
    projection = np.stack((rot_1, rot_2, rot_3, translation)).T
    return np.dot(camera_parameters, projection)

def hex_to_rgb(hex_color):
    hex_color = hex_color.lstrip('#')
    h_len = len(hex_color)
    return tuple(int(hex_color[i:i + h_len // 3], 16) for i in range(0, h_len, h_len // 3))

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Augmented reality application')

parser.add_argument('-r','--rectangle', help = 'draw rectangle delimiting target surface on frame', action = 'store_true')
parser.add_argument('-mk','--model_keypoints', help = 'draw model keypoints', action = 'store_true')
parser.add_argument('-fk','--frame_keypoints', help = 'draw frame keypoints', action = 'store_true')
parser.add_argument('-ma','--matches', help = 'draw matches between keypoints', action = 'store_true')

args = parser.parse_args()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**objloader_simple.py** (place in the same folder with main.py)

```
class OBJ:
    def __init__(self, filename, swapyz=False):
        """Loads a Wavefront OBJ file. """
        self.vertices = []
        self.normals = []
        self.texcoords = []
        self.faces = []
        material = None
        for line in open(filename, "r"):
            if line.startswith('#'): continue
            values = line.split()
            if not values: continue
            if values[0] == 'v':
                v = list(map(float, values[1:4]))
                if swapyz:
                    v = v[0], v[2], v[1]
                self.vertices.append(v)
            elif values[0] == 'vn':
                v = list(map(float, values[1:4]))
                if swapyz:
                    v = v[0], v[2], v[1]
                self.normals.append(v)
            elif values[0] == 'vt':
                self.texcoords.append(map(float, values[1:3]))
            #elif values[0] in ('usemtl', 'usemat'):
                #material = values[1]
            #elif values[0] == 'mtllib':
                #self.mtl = MTL(values[1])
            elif values[0] == 'f':
                face = []
                texcoords = []
                norms = []
                for v in values[1:]:
                    w = v.split('/')
                    face.append(int(w[0]))
                    if len(w) >= 2 and len(w[1]) > 0:
                        texcoords.append(int(w[1]))
                    else:
                        texcoords.append(0)
                    if len(w) >= 3 and len(w[2]) > 0:
                        norms.append(int(w[2]))
                    else:
                        norms.append(0)
                #self.faces.append((face, norms, texcoords, material))
                self.faces.append((face, norms, texcoords))
```

**fox.obj** (place in the same folder with main.py)
fox.obj is over the characters limitation, so I post download link below for the fox.obj
https://free3d.com/3d-model/tibetan-hill-fox-v1--444273.html

**model.jpg** (place in the same folder with main.py) is the card can be anything we want. Not the key point in this case. So I am not posting here.

How can I alter the code and run the main.py to make it can detect the model.jpg and show the 3D fox normally?

Comment: It seems like too much code to handle normally, you probably should subdivide the task to concentrate on the part that fails (projecting the fox or finding the card)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the homography matrix manually such that it will be at fixed position. But there is a catch you cannot actually rotation and translation. The homography must be somehow be eliminated.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31388695)